# Enterprise Mode rather than Compatibility mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have an old ASP.NET application that doesn't work properly on IE 11 *Edge mode* so that I have added compatibility mode by adding the following in the web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=5" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

However it doens't work for some reason. Testing *Dev Tools* of IE11 I found out that changing *Browser Profile* to Enterprise works out.

My question is: Shouldn't compatibility mode really work like that?
How can I enable **Enterprise Mode** on server to my application?

Comment: It looks like you would add your application to the browsers list of Enterprise Mode sites  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx

Comment: @rogerdeuce thank you. I found out that there is a list of sites that should go on Compatibility Mode in my company. It's an XML and  its path is encountered on windows registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode\  key name: SiteList